# Python creating a tempdirectory with multiple files

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am trying to create a temporary directory, where can I write a temporary file (for docker image and .sh scripts), and then I will run docker script to build from that entire directory as image,
then remove the temporary directory.
However I can't open the temporary directory to write to:

```
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print(temp_dir.name)
with open (temp_dir.name, 'w') as rsh:
    rsh.write('echo test')
```

I get the error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\j\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpdwhmvt61'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write data into a directory, try to create a file in your temporary directory.

Comment: Is it recommended to create a file in that temporary folder, then delete the folder later on? Or should I create a temporary file in a temporary folder

Comment: Opening the folder directly on windows explorer gives an error, it looks like folder does not exist, despite me not deleting the folder?

Comment: yes, this is a good way when you want build an image with a temperary directory as it's context.

Comment: the temporary folder create by `TemporaryDirectory()` will be deleted automately after your `temp_dir` collected by GC . if you don't want delete it, try use internal `tempfile.mkdtemp()`